# How to model an interacton between a categorical IV and a continous moderator (created through a CFA) in a SEM model using the lavaan package in R?

Tags: categorical-data, interaction, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

**How can one go about modelling the interaction between a categorical independent variable and a continous moderator (created through a CFA) in a SEM model using the lavaan package in R?**

In particular, in my real dataset I am essentially interested in re-creating a two-way ANOVA in SEM, and also want to include a moderating variable to test with each factor variable.

Example data and problem:

```
### load packages: ###
library(dplyr)
library(lavaan)
library(car)
library(psychTools)

### Create some data: ###

# Dependent variable: Taken example data from psychTools
DV1 <- bfi$A1 # item 1 
DV2 <- bfi$A2 # item 2
DV3 <- bfi$A3 # item 3

# Moderating variable: Taken example data from psychTools
MOD1 <- bfi$C1 # item 1
MOD2 <- bfi$C2 # item 2
MOD3 <- bfi$C3 # item 3

# Create example factor variables
x1 <- c("A","B")
x2 <- c("C","D")
set.seed(1)
FAC1 <- as.factor(sample(x1, 200, replace = TRUE)) # Factor 1, with two levels "A" and "B"
FAC2 <- as.factor(sample(x2, 200, replace = TRUE)) # Factor 2, with two levels "C" and "D"
FAC12 <- interaction(FAC1,FAC2) # Factor 12, interaction of FAC1 and FAC2, with four levels "A.C" "B.C" "A.D" "B.D"

# Combine to data frame
StudyData <- data.frame(DV1,DV2,DV3, 
                        MOD1,MOD2,MOD3,
                        FAC1, FAC2, FAC12)

### Make all categorical variables numeric for use in SEM (orthogonal contrast coded as in ANOVA): ###

StudyData$FAC1 <- recode(StudyData$FAC1, "c('A')='-1';
                                          c('B')='1'")
StudyData$FAC1 <- as.numeric(levels(StudyData$FAC1))[StudyData$FAC1]

StudyData$FAC2 <- recode(StudyData$FAC2, "c('C')='-1';
                                          c('D')='1'")
StudyData$FAC2 <- as.numeric(levels(StudyData$FAC2))[StudyData$FAC2]

StudyData$FAC12 <- recode(StudyData$FAC12, "c('A.D','B.C')='-1';
                                          c('A.C','B.D')='1'")
StudyData$FAC12 <- as.numeric(levels(StudyData$FAC12))[StudyData$FAC12]

### SEM Model One: ###
Model.one <- '
# cfa
DV =~ DV1 + DV2 + DV3
MOD =~ MOD1 + MOD2 + MOD3
# regressions
DV ~ FAC1 + FAC2 + FAC12
'

Modelone <- sem(Model.one, StudyData, estimator="MLM", effect.coding=TRUE, meanstructure=TRUE) 
summary(Modelone)
fitMeasures(Modelone, c("chisq","cfi","rmsea","srmr","nfi","gfi"))

### SEM Model Two: ###
Model.two <- '
# cfa
DV =~ DV1 + DV2 + DV3
MOD =~ MOD1 + MOD2 + MOD3
# regressions
DV ~ FAC1 + FAC1:MOD + FAC2 + FAC12
'

Modeltwo <- sem(Model.two, StudyData, estimator="MLM", effect.coding=TRUE, meanstructure=TRUE) 
summary(Modeltwo)
fitMeasures(Modeltwo, c("chisq","cfi","rmsea","srmr","nfi","gfi"))

### EDIT ###

### SEM Model Three: ###
Model.three <- '
# cfa
DV =~ DV1 + DV2 + DV3
MOD =~ MOD1 + MOD2 + MOD3
# regressions
DV ~ FAC2 + MOD
'

Modelthree <- sem(Model.three, StudyData, estimator="MLM", effect.coding=TRUE, meanstructure=TRUE, group="FAC1") 
summary(Modelthree)
fitMeasures(Modelthree, c("chisq","cfi","rmsea","srmr","nfi","gfi"))
```

Model one runs fine. I can run my "ANOVA" in the SEM environment.

However, when I want to run Model two, which includes an interaction term between FAC1 and MOD (as created via CFA in the SEM model), I receive the error:

"lavaan WARNING:
The variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters (vcov)
does not appear to be positive definite! The smallest eigenvalue
(= -3.458498e-20) is smaller than zero. This may be a symptom that
the model is not identified."

**Questions**:

1. Is it not possible to create a factor:continuous interaction in
   lavaan in this manner?
2. Are there any work arounds & how to do them? (For example, extract the values calculated during the CFA for MOD and calculate FAC1:MOD interaction outside of the SEM, then re-use the variable in the path analysis (regressions) part of the SEM)
3. Can Mplus do this without the need for work arounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, the `:` operator only works on observed variables.  It triggers `lavaan` to actually calculate the product term and include it in the covariance matrix and mean vector to which the model is fitted.  That cannot be what happens with a latent variable, which is not part of the observed variables' summary statistics.
2. Moderation is symmetric, so you could use a multigroup model, with the categorical IV as the grouping variable.  Differences in the `DV~MOD` simple effects across groups would be moderation by `FAC1`.  Differences in the `DV~1` intercepts across groups would be the simple effect of `FAC1`, which could be probed by centering `MOD`'s mean at different values.  Or you might be able to use the `emmeans` utility in the `semTools` package to probe the interaction; see the  `?lavaan2emmeans` help-page examples.  I suggest another possibility below.

   - Note that using this approach would make the `Fac12` variable redundant because `Fac2`'s intercept and effects are likewise moderated by `Fac1` by virtue of parameters differing across groups.
3. Yes, M*plus* can simply use LMS estimation, but that is fraught with some restrictive assumptions.  My student's PhD [research](https://doi.org/10.3758/s13428-018-1151-3) (also [here](https://doi.org/10.1080/10705511.2020.1766357)) has revealed that the product-indicator approach is less restrictive, and that can be implemented in `lavaan` (see [her tutorial](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-77249-3_20) about using this method for invariance testing, available for download from [my faculty page](http://www.uva.nl/profile/t.d.jorgensen)).

Comment: **On 2:** I understand I can add a single categorical grouping variable e.g., 'group ="FAC1"', referring to my code this could be FAC1, FAC2, or the interaction term FAC12. However, in factorial ANOVA it is common to include both _main_ _effects_ and the _interaction_ _term_. Thus, the grouping variable method is not suitable for this, correct? I won't be able to estimate main effects and the interaction in an ANOVA-like fashion (as code for 'SEM Model One' currently does). Isn't it misleading to not include main effects and only examine the interaction term levels with a grouping var?

Comment: In your OP, `mod` only interacted with `Fac1`, so interpret my (2) in that context.  But using `group="Fac1"` still includes its interaction with `Fac2` because `Fac2`'s effects can differ across `Fac1` groups. But that means you can (must) exclude the redundant `Fac12` from your model.  I will edit my post above to state that.

Comment: But by doing it the way you mention, I would be unable to estimate main effects for `FAC2` or `MOD` right? As they always depend on the grouping variable. To refer to my new example (see SEM model 3, original post edited), this basically shows the interaction between `FAC1` and `FAC2`, and `FAC1` and `MOD`. If I wanted to estimate main effects of `FAC1`, I could instead use `DV ~ 0*FAC2 + 0*MOD`… but there is no way to estimate `FAC2` or `MODs` main effects while still using a grouping variable, correct?

Comment: If you want main effects, you can either define new parameters (with the `:=` operator) in your Model 3 script that are the average intercepts across groups, or you can fit a model with their effects constrained to equality across groups.  With balanced/equal *N*s, both should provide the same result.  With unequal *N*s, the latter provides estimates that are weighted (by *N*) averages, as opposed the unweighted average effects in the former.  Either way, the `MOD` effects are only comparable across groups if you impose measurement-invariance constraints on `MOD`'s loadings and intercepts.